# Any way to simulate a mousedown event in CreateJS?

Tags: flash, events, easeljs, createjs

In CreateJS, apparently the only way for an element to receive *pressmove* events is for it to first receive a *mousedown* event. However, there seems to be a bug in the current version of CreateJS where if the content of a container changes after the initial mousedown, it fails to continue receiving pressmove events. So as a workaround I need some way to programmatically have the container re-press itself or otherwise notify the API that it wants to receive that event.

If it makes a difference, this is using the version of CreateJS embedded in Flash CC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your issue is simply to set `mouseChildren=false` on the container. This will make your container the target for mouse events, instead of its children, so the target doesn't change in between events. Here's an example of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/vg5qd0qa/

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!